Handle multiple api call using riverpod on same page
How to use Riverpod to efficiently call multiple APIs on the same page one by one, especially when some APIs are dependent on the response of others.Please give example also.

Do you have any specific problem you're trying to solve? But generally, follow this guide on the docs: Combining requests

To handle multiple API calls using Riverpod in a Flutter application, you can use FutureProvider or Provider combined with AsyncValue to represent the asynchronous result of the API calls
Step 1 : Define API Call Function
Future<String> FirstFunction() async {
  return 'First API Data';
}

Future<String> SecondFunction() async {

  return 'Second API Data';
}

Additional if you like to add delay
// Simulate API call delay
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

Step 2 : Define providers
final firstDataFutureProvider = FutureProvider((ref) => FirstFunction());
final secondDataFutureProvider = FutureProvider((ref) => SecondFunction());
Step 3: Use providers in widgets
Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
                  final firstDataState = watch(firstDataFutureProvider);
                  return firstDataState.when(
                    loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error: $error'),
                    data: (data) => Text('First API Data: $data'),
                  );
                }),
                Consumer(builder: (context, watch, _) {
                  final secondDataState = watch(secondDataFutureProvider);
                  return secondDataState.when(
                    loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error: $error'),
                    data: (data) => Text('Second API Data: $data'),
                  );

